# How to reassign object method/Property to new Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have stumbled upon something interesting. When I create a new object setting a new key for a method, it doesnt handle it correctly when trying to access (use) it. Please see the example below:

```
const cases = [
  { instance: instance.mydecorator, triggerEffects: useMyDecorator },
];
```

then I want to loop through as follows:

```
cases.forEach(({ instance, triggerEffects }) => {
  instance = [
    Story => {
      triggerEffects();
      return <Story />;
    },
  ];
});
```

the example above doesn not work: instance != instance.mydecorator, so the array is not set correctly.

What works is:

```
const cases = [
  { instance: instance, triggerEffects: useMyDecorator },
];

cases.forEach(({ instance, triggerEffects }) => {
  instance.mydecorator = [
    Story => {
      triggerEffects();
      return <Story />;
    },
  ];
});
```

Comment: It's the same reason why `const obj = {x: 1}; let x = obj.x; x = 2;` doesn't update `obj`, it's not a ReactJS thing, it's a JS thing. `x` holds the value of `obj.x` (in this case 1, its more or less the same as writing `let x = 1`), `x` isn't "linked" in a sense where updating it will update `obj`

Comment: try without destructuring  cases.forEach((item) => { item.instance = () =>{ }})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is destructure you are using in foreach callback input parameters - this part => `cases.forEach(({ instance, triggerEffects })...`. When you do like this you destructured array element, and when looking your array declaration instance points to some other instance object, so in destructure `{ instance, triggerEffects }` instance will point to right side instance from your array declaration - you basically accessed(marked with THIS ONE) to `const cases = [ { instance: instance(THIS ONE), triggerEffects: useMyDecorator }, ];` and not the one on the left side as you were expecting.

What you need to do is to avoid destructure in this case, since you do not want to modify that right side instance, but actual element of the array. Do like this:

```
 cases.forEach(element => {
  element.instance = [
    Story => {
      element.triggerEffects();
      return <Story />;
    },
  ];
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I see it really is that way, although I dont completely understand why. How is destructering different then passing it as whole? I didnt think there is a difference between the two. Interesting. and THANK YOU

Comment: Because when using desctructure you are accessing value immediately, meaning that destructured `instance` will point to that (right side)instance you were assigned as value initially when declaring cases array. When working with complex objects in array  destructure can be dangerous because of situations like this, because it really is not that much intuitive at first look. Simply `instance` from { instance, triggerEffects} points to `[ {instance: instance(TO THIS), ..}, ... ]` because (TO THIS) is the value you accessed immediately in destructure, and you end up modifying wrong object.